# Calling method of object created in embedded block on click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am beginner in ASP.NET and after lot of searching I've decided to ask you guys.

So, I have object created in embedded block in my Page.aspx in following way:

```
<% Invoice invoice = InvoiceGateway.get(1); %>
```

Implementation of these is in different files Invoice.cs and InvoiceGateway.cs 
I am using it to fill webelements right where I need it in this way:

```
<p class="list-group-item-text"><%= invoice.getCreator().getAddress() %></p>
```

But now I've started to create buttons and I am trying to call method of this object when I click the button e.g.

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" runat="server" onServerClick="<% invoice.delete() %>">
     delete
</a>
```

I know this is not correct, its just for illustration of what I am trying to achieve.

I am not sure how (or even if) I can do that. I know I can define some function in .aspx.cs page and call it onServerClick, or just redirect to `Page.aspx?delete={id}` and perform something on load.

My question is... Is there a way how to call method of such created object, after I click some hyperlink/button/etc? I've come up with some alternatives, but nothing that would use this already created object and its method.

Comment: The way to do that would either be that redirect you mention or create a server-side handler which does what you need and invoke it via AJAX on a client-side click.  Server-side code and client-side code can't directly interact in the way you're trying.

Comment: So the correct way how to achieve calling methods of that already created object would be to create it in Page.aspx.cs and then in onServerClick call method that is defined there? I was trying to avoid using onPageLoad and went straight to embedded like I was used to in PHP. Thanks for help :)

Comment: This wouldn't work in PHP either.  It has nothing to do with the language being used and everything to do with the fundamentals of web development.  In your page, server-side code executes *in its entirety* on the server and the final resulting page is sent to the client.  That "already created object" no longer exists by the time the page is sent to the client.

Comment: I see now, I didn't realize that the object no longer exists, so what I am trying to do is entirely pointless. I will just create the serverside handler and handle deletion there. Thank you for your help :)